# Spring Security + custom User object attached to session for filtered requests

Tags: security, hibernate, spring, spring-security

I am not sure how to solve the following problem/ realize my scenario. Maybe someone can give me some hints?

1. I have a Spring MVC app with Spring Security. I also use a custom Login page. All works fine so far, I can authenticate and display the logged in user on my JSP using the following code.

   `<sec:authorize ifAnyGranted="ROLE_USER">`

   `Logged in as <sec:authentication property="principal.username" />`

   `</sec:authorize>`
2. The users a re retreieved from a database right now. Code for that in XML is

   `<jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
               users-by-username-query="SELECT username, password , '1' AS enabled FROM users WHERE username = ?"
               authorities-by-username-query="SELECT username, 'ROLE_USER' FROM users WHERE username = ?" />`

All works fine. Problem is, I actually have a custom User class that I would like to use and probably keep in my session as later DB requests should filter the results according to the logged in User.id.

How would I do this?

- What do I need to do to store my User object in my session? Is this the right way to do it?
- I use Hibernate. What is Best pratice to filter request, e.g. for objects called "Task" (in a task manager), according to the logged in user? (I have a column and property user_id in the tasks-table in my MySQL DB)

Any help or hint is much appreciated. Just need some direction :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring Security 3.x, you may want to check if [Expression Based Access Control](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html) (`@PostFilter`, for instance) meets your requirement.

For instance, if your `Task` objects has the `username` member, you could do something like this...

```
   @PostFilter("filterObject.username == authentication.name")
   public List<Task> getTasks() {
        ...
        tasks = TaskDao.findAll();
        return tasks;
    }
```

This would return those tasks which belonged to the logged in user.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3891622/spring-hibernate-filter-by-current-user-id) SO discussion is also possibly relevant.

Comment: I do use Spring 3. I have expressions enabled in my XML, but I don't see how that can help me to attach a custom user to the session and filter subsequent Hibernate calls?

Comment: @Czar. Updated answer based on your comment.

Comment: @Raghuram: Thanks for the update. I do understand your approach. But two more questions: 1. Would this approach not create a lot of overhead? As I see it the TaskDAO.findAll() will return all Tasks, but the returned list will be filtered. Right? This reads more data from DB than necessary. (see also your link) 2. Do you know what is best: use the "standard" usernae from SecurityContextHolder, use that to get the Domain Object via DAO and then use the Domain object's ID property in subsequent DAO/service calls, or replace the UserDetails with a custom one representing "my" user DOmain object?

Comment: @Czar. For ques 1. You are right. This was a contrived example. For ques 2. I would think custom UserDetails would be better.  The first approach would involve two calls for every service invocation.

Comment: @Raghuram: I quickly checked, the @PostFilter would work and filter the results properly. So "+1" for that, thanks. But actually I think I would prefer to use filtered queries to minimize DB traffic. Can you maybe giv eme some hints on how to use a custom user, store it in session and use that for my calls in service/DAO layer?

Comment: I guess I will have to work with the Spring Security filter chain somehow: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html. Any experience with this? Where can I hook into to add (Version 3 compliant) additional info after Login without messing too much with my current XML configuration? Using a custom  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter seems to require a lot of changes...